# Dúvida Sobre Váriavel e Função

Tags: funções, loop, condição

Pessoal estou iniciando em Python, com a seguintes caracteristicas:
-Usuário entra com temperatura limite
-Leio a temperatura do usuário comparo com a do sensor
-Se temperatura do Sensor for > Temeratura do Usuário 
 Ativa Cooler e acende LED Vermelho
 Senão acende LED verde.
-O loop é interrompido pelo Ctrl+C KeyboardInterrupt

Dúvidas de acordo com o código abaixo:
  Porque os LEDs não estão acendendo em nenhuma condição ? Mas sei que eles   funcionam, por que já testei em outro código.
  Porque quando executo pela primeira vez o código, entro com o valor que ative o cooler, interrompo com o Ctrl+C. Em Seguida quando executo novamente o código o cooler liga novamente sem entrar com nenhum valor como se não fosse limpo o valor da variável antes ? Já tentei usar o del para deletar a variável mas não resolveu.

[Link para o repositório Git com o código](https://github.com/rleme/python/blob/master/check_temp.py)

Comment: Com relação aos LED resolvido falha na minha lógica onde eu ligava e no mesmo segundo delisgava o LED.

Mas ainda não consegui resolver o problema da variavel.